# How to have multiple sections with a height of 100%

Tags: html, css

I have four sections that I want to be 100% height, but they overflow from the body tag. Is that okay or is there a proper way to get this effect?

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #171717;
}

section:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #193856;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</body>
```

Comment: remove the height from the body then

Comment: You can check the section outside the body like this - `height: calc (100vh - 1px);` for the tag `<section>`. After that, you will see at the bottom 1 pixel of the next section.